# Use two excludeSwitches when launching Selenium Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to use Chrome as a service to display a fullscreen webpage on a screen.
I'm tackling this challenge by creating a python script which uses Selenium to direct chrome to the correct page, and to format the site correctly. Due to the main requirement being a display it's important that the displayed webpage is unobstructed. There are two obstructions in my instance that can both be dealt with by using different excludeSwitches options:

To disable the automation bar:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']);
```

To disable the 'Disable developer mode extensions' popup:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['load-extension'])
```

However I've not found a way to implement both at the same time - I've tried:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"excludeSwitches": ['enable-automation'], "excludeSwitches": ['load-extension']});
```

```
prefs = {"excludeSwitches": ['enable-automation, load-extension'], "excludeSwitches": ['load-extension', 'enable-automation']}

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs);
```

In these cases only one of these have the intended effect, depending on order. How can I get my syntax correct to apply both of these options?

Test code (excluding imports):

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"excludeSwitches": ['enable-automation', 'load-extension']})

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(('https://www.google.co.uk'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[excludeSwitches](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) is a list of strings

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['load-extension', 'enable-automation'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just tried this, seems to successfully prevent the 'Disable developer mode extensions' pop up, but does not prevent the automation bar from appearing.

Comment: @MBrooks I'm doing it without `"prefs"`, see updated answer (atleast 'enable-automation').